# Consulta entre datas Mysql mostrando todos os dias do intervalo

Tags: mysql

Tenho um sistema de *e-commerce* no qual são vendidos N produtos e estou fazendo um comparativo entre vendas de um determinado produto por período de tempo, ou seja, o *admin* vai ter uma área no qual ele escolhe um produto e um *range* de data (ex: 01/04/2018 - 26/04/2018) para plotar isso num gráfico de linha possibilitando ver a evolução de vendas desse produto ao longo do tempo.

Existe alguma forma, no MySQL mesmo, de fazer com que mesmo as datas que não tenham vendas, apareça como 0? Sei que poderia gerar esse range com PHP e buscar 1 a 1 e gerar um `array` disso, mas queria saber se tem alguma forma direto no MySQL.

Exemplo:

```
Produto A
Data Inicial: 01/04/2018
Data Final: 05/04/2018

01/04 - 01 vendidos
02/04 - 04 vendidos
03/04 - 00 vendidos
04/04 - 06 vendidos
05/04 - 00 vendidos
```

O resultado dessa consulta seria somente

```
01/04 - 01 vendidos
02/04 - 04 vendidos
04/04 - 06 vendidos
```

Queria que os dias zerados também aparecessem.

Comment: Será que um SELECT COUNT(*) AS total já não mostra essa quantidade 0?

Comment: Achei esse tópido no SOEN https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046865/mysql-select-all-dates-in-a-range-even-if-no-records-present

Comment: http://www.media-division.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps

Comment: Galera, tratei no PHP mesmo, mas a ideia do SOEN que o Pedro postou pode ser que funcione, a do Leo precisa de procedure, que tbm não seria interessante, mais facil tratar na aplicação.

Marcolla M, não pois nesse caso só apareceria as que tivesse linhas pra contar.

Answer (score 0):

O que você precisa fazer é consultar o intervalo pretendido com MySQL e depois com o PHP você faz a interação e mostra todos os dias e condiciona para que os dias que não forem retornados sejam exibidos como 0.

`WHERE
   DATE(data) > DATE(:inicial)
   AND DATE(data) < DATE(:final)`

Answer (score 0):

Pergunta antiga mas atualmente há uma solução mais elegante suportada a partir do MySQL versão 8, usando um [*common table expression* (cláusula `WITH`) recursivo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive).

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte_count (n) 
AS (
      SELECT 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT n + 1 
      FROM cte_count 
      WHERE n < 5
    )
SELECT n 
FROM cte_count
# left join com os dias ...
;
```